# Globally configure Jackson properties using Spring?

Tags: json, spring, jackson

i am using Jackson and was wondering if it is possible to set global properties using resources.xml?

Example:
In some places i need to do:

```
jsonMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

It would be nice that i can configure Jackson to do this global using spring resources.xml,
any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily, just extend the `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` class and specify all your properties in the constructor(or you can accept a map as well): Then autowire your own ObjectMapper where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box -- but maybe someone could build such an extension, release as Jackson module?